# TableLayout crushes button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I'm experiencing a strange issue with a `TableLayout` next to a `Button`. This is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">   
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:stretchColumns="*"              
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >    
        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Column 1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button2"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"           
        android:text="Button 2" />                          
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is what I get:

[image: Screenshot]

This is confusing me. As you can see, both the `Button` and the `TableLayout` have a `layout_weight` of 1. So I'd expect them to have the same width inside the `LinearLayout` but for some reason, the `TableLayout` takes up much more space and pushes the button all the way to the right.

How can I have the additional space available in the `LinearLayout` distributed among the `TableLayout` and the `Button` according to the value set in `layout_weight` please?

Note that I don't want to use a `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`. I'm specifically looking for a `LinearLayout` solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your parent. and make width `0dp` of both child

> android:weightSum="2"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Column 1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set `android:layout_width="0dp"` for both `Button` and `TableLayout`