# How can I use TableLayout with WRAP_CONTENT?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I'm having a hard time getting `wrap_content` to work with `TableLayout`. Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">   
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:stretchColumns="*"              
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >    
        <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Column 1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:text="Column 2" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button2"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"           
        android:text="Button 2" />                          
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, although `layout_weight` of the `TableLayout` and the `Button` are both 1, the button is crushed to the right.

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51611175/tablelayout-crushes-button), I know I can solve this by setting the `layout_width` of the `TableLayout` to `0dp` but I don't want to do that. I specifically want to use `wrap_content` as the `layout_width` for the `TableLayout` because using `0dp` instead of `wrap_content` has an implication that I don't want.

Namely, when using `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`, `LinearLayout` will assume a width of 0 for the `TableLayout` and then distribute the remaining space among all children. When using `wrap_content`, however, `LinearLayout` will first compute the minimum width of the child, subtract it from the remaining space, and then distribute the remaining space among the children, which will lead to quite different results which are important for my specific use case.

That's why I need to find a way to use `wrap_content` with `TableLayout`. When using a `LinearLayout` instead of a `TableLayout`, setting `layout_width` to `wrap_content` works fine. It's only `TableLayout` that doesn't seem to be compatible with `wrap_content`. Is this an Android bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: what exactly do you want i din't get it can you pain the view.

Comment: I want to use `wrap_content` for `layout_width` of the `TableLayout`, together with `layout_weight` of 1. The issue is in the distribution of space inside the `LinearLayout`. Assume the `LinearLayout` width is 1000 units and there are two children with `layout_width` set to 0 and `layout_weight` set to 1. Each will get 500 units. Now if the `layout_width` of both children is set to `wrap_content` and `layout_weight` to 1, Android will first subtract the minimum width of each child from the 1000 units and then distribute the remaining space...

Comment: ...for example if the width of `TableLayout` is 200 and the width of the `Button` is 100, then only 700 units will be left to distribute in the `LinearLayout`. The `TableLayout` will get an additional 350 and the `Button` too so the final width will be 550 for the `TableLayout` and 450 for the `Button`. That's the difference between setting `layout_width` to `wrap_content` or to 0.

Comment: ok i get it your point

Answer (score 0):

make android:layout_width="0dp"`

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Column 1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Column 2" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 2" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but please read my post again. I specifically *don't* want to set `layout_width` to 0dp.

Comment: try to make Button android:layout_width="match_parent" and TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: I also want the button to use `wrap_content`.

Comment: that means you want to Button and TableLayout always android:layout_width="wrap_content" but distributed in same ratio like using android:layout_width="0dp"?

Comment: See my comments below my original post. I think this explains it really well. I don't want the distribution like with 0dp but like with wrap_content.